# Combining a Parser using andThen to create another Parser of different type

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I'm trying to parse a data using combinator parsers to return a 
Parser[java.util.Date]

I do that in two phases, first, I parse a year using a simpleYear 
Parser, then I tried to plug in the result of this simple parser into
andThen, I would then manipulate this input to have as output of this andThen
a ParseResult[Date]:

Sadly I get the following error from the compiler at the line of declaration:

```
       type mismatch; found : 
parser.DateParser.Input ⇒ parser.DateParser.ParseResult[java.util.Date] (which 
     expands to) 
    scala.util.parsing.input.Reader[Char] ⇒ parser.DateParser.ParseResult[java.util. required: parser.DateParser.Parser[java.util.Date]
```

here is the code:

```
object DateParser extends RegexParsers {
        val formatter: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        def year = """\d{4}""".r
        def month: Parser[String] = 
        def day = """[0-2]\d""".r | """3[01]""".r
        def month = """0\d""".r | """1[0-2]""".r
        def simpleDate: Parser[String] =
            (year ~ "-" ~ month ~ "-" ~ day) ^^
                { case y ~ "-" ~ m ~ "-" ~ d => y + "-" + m + "-" + d }

        def date: Parser[Date] = simpleDate andThen {
            case Success(s, in) =>
                val x: ParseResult[Date] = try {
                    Success(formatter.parse(s), in)
                } catch {
                    case pe: ParseException => Failure("date format invalid", in)
                }
                x
            case f: Failure => f
        }
}
```

It seems that the scala compiler can't do an implicit conversion itself
of the type of date into a Parser[Date](maybe because of the try/catch?)

Is there some other way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parser[T]` is a subclass of a function `Input => ParseResult[T]` and the method `andThen` you are using comes from the function. You are passing to it a function `ParseResult[String] => ParseResult[Date]`, so you get back `Input => ParseResult[Date]`, which doesn't match the type `Parser[Date]`, and that's why you get this error.

But you can simply wrap a function of type `Input => ParseResult[T]` in a `Parser` method to get a `Parser[T]`. So you can define `date` like this:

```
def date: Parser[Date] = Parser(simpleDate andThen {
  // Cleaned up `Success` case a bit
  case Success(s, in) =>
    try Success(formatter.parse(s), in)
    catch {
      case pe: ParseException => Failure("date format invalid", in)
    }
  // It's better to use `NoSuccess` instead of `Failure`, 
  // to cover the `Error` case as well.
  case f: NoSuccess => f
})
```

---

That said, it's not the best/cleanest method. As you want to call a function on the parser result to modify it somehow, you can use the `Parser`'s methods `map` and `flatMap` or their equivalents (`map` equivalent to `^^`, `flatMap` equivalent to `into` and `>>`). Those have the same idea as `map` and `flatMap` of other Scala classes such as `Try` or `Future`.

In this case you have to account for the possibility of failure, so you have to use `flatMap`. A definition of `date` using `flatMap` may look like this:

```
def date: Parser[Date] = simpleDate >> (s =>
  try success(formatter.parse(s))
  catch { case pe: ParseException => failure("date format invalid") })
```

---

Also, you may want (if you hadn't already done it yourself) to set `formatter` to be non-lenient: `formatter.setLenient(false)`. Otherwise it will do things like parsing `2000-02-31` as the 2nd of March!

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, and also all the other tips. I was wondering how come you can use the apply method of Parser on Input => ParseResult[Date] and get back a Parser[Date]?
I checked the api: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser 
but it's not visibly listed as legal.

Comment: @Simonlbc It's a method in `Parsers` http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers You are extending `RegexParsers` which extends `Parsers`, so you can call it.